# Vuetify Tooltip use in Pug.js

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js, pug

I am new to vue and pug.js. I am following the vuetify tutorial to put tooltip. It come out error.

The vuetify code shows:

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
     <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
       <span
         v-bind="attrs"
         v-on="on"
       >This text has a tooltip</span>
     </template>
     <span>Tooltip</span>
   </v-tooltip>
```

And I try to put it into pug.js, and it failed.

```
    v-tooltip(bottom)
      template(v-slot="activator:{on,attrs}")
          span This is a span
      span ToolTip span
```

Comment: Does it work with regular HTML? Do you have an error when it fails?